# Quick save data on disk; how to? Use a auxiliary memory buffer?

Tags: c#, memory, buffer

I wrote an application in c # to read some data (in polling mode) from some devices connected on ethernet network. Many parallel tasks are started, one for each device configured; at the end of all tasks, the readed data are stored in a stringbuilder and then saved to file in append mode. All works fine if the polling time is set high (eg greater than 5/6 seconds). For shorter times it may happen that the disk IO activities fail to save the amount of data contained in the strinbuilder (first saving process is not yet ended when the second process of saving data need to start and so on ...). How can I solve this problem? I thought of creating a control like to "memory buffer", that copy the stringbuilder (sbData) populated with the device data into a support stringbuilder (sbAux) used to save the data at fixed time (eg every 30 seconds). Once the data have been successfully saved, copy the new data again at the end of the 30 seconds (sbAux = sbData). Are there other ways? Can you advise me on this?

Thanks a lot to everyone for any advice.

Comment: You're saving input from several different source to just 1 file? If so, why not 1 file per device? What does the file have to look like if it's saved correctly?

Comment: Even if i save the data for each device in a different file, the problem remains. If I do quick readings and between two consecutive readings there is no time to open the file from the harddisk, insert the data in APPEND mode and then save the file, however I need to create a buffer in memory. Which is the best solution to create a circular buffer in memory?

Comment: How much data are you writing and how often? Without code it's very hard to help you, I'm afraid. Generally I would expect using a file stream to cope with this - you just push data at it and it decides when to write to disk. But is your process continuous? Or do you gather data for a set time then write the results to disk and it's finished? The best answer might be to write the data to 1 file as you were doing and separate it out later, or you might be fine keeping it separate at write time. Without something more specific it's hard to help. Could you post a bit of code?

Comment: Adam for now i have only a skeletor of windows service and some .dll to manage the devices connection, read program configuration file (.ini file) and log some actions / exceptions. When the service start (OnStart) starting many task as number of devices. Each task reading in polling mode the datas (e.g. device "01" read holding registers 00, 01, 02 each 1000msec, device "02" read holding registers 03,04,05 each 200msec and so on ...).

Comment: The "polling time" i set inside the configuration file of application. The basic request from my customer is to save all data reading from all device inside a single file in append mode; i create a new file per day (e.g. 181002_LogData.csv, 181003_LogData.csv ...). The data reading tasks will stop only when the device go offline or when the windows service will put on stop mode. The problem: if the data will be readed more fast than the IO activities (IO activities = save data on disk) what is the best way to store data in memory and save it on disk when the previows save data will be ended?

Comment: That makes things a bit more clear. Do you have to wait for data to be ready? Or does the register you read respond immediately? How many registers (in total) do you have to read? Let's say there are only 10 registers and they all respond immediately. Then one thread should just read them all, output the data and then sleep until it's time to poll again. But if there are 1000 registers and they take 1/2 second each to respond then the problem is much more difficult to solve. How long it takes to read the data is quite an important factor in this.

Comment: Usually i use devices with Modbus TCP protocol; the Mdbus TCP allows reading up to 120 holding registers ad a time. The response time may be about 50 / 100 msec (normal conditions) or many second if the device not response (timeout).

Comment: Consider e.g. 2 devices; starting 2 parallel task with a different polling time (e.g. 100 and 200 msec). In normal condition, the two task append the data on the same buffer like this
timestamp_100; device_01;data_01;data_02 ...data_nn
timestamp_200; device_01;data_01;data_02 ...data_nn
timestamp_200; device_02;data_01;data_02....data_nn
timestamp_300; device_01;data_01;data_02 ...data_nn
timestamp_400; device_01;data_01;data_02 ...data_nn
timestamp_400; device_02;data_01;data_02....data_nn
... and so on ...

Comment: First problem i need to implement a lock on the tasks for manage the same "buffer" and append data on the same object. Then (second problem) i need to understand the "idea" to write a routine (lauch a new task) to save a portion of buffer data on disk and mark them and "at the same time" read data from device and save in the buffer. I can't realize "the idea / the concept" (on my mind) for write a routine for manage a buffer data like to explaied before ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - you're going to have to forget keeping all the data in nice neat rows if the time taken to read the data can be anything from 50 to x,000 milliseconds. Instead I would suggest TWO stages.

Your first stage is a buffer which is *really* fast and just accepts data as quickly as possible. It performs minimal checking - just to ensure that the data is in the right format, for example. You'll have to decide on what "minimal checking" means but it will only throw out obviously wrong data (probably by just ignoring it and logging a warning, maybe). Anything else just gets added to the queue. A queue is aimed at data being added to the back of the queue and read from the front. You have to decide how much data it can hold as a maximum and only experimentation will tell you that.

You can find information on how to use a queue at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.enqueue?view=netframework-4.7.2
- http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-queue

You will have to inherit from Queue to suit your own data and make it thread safe since more than 1 thread will be writing to it and reading from it.

Your worker threads read from the devices and submit readings as they become available. They don't try to order the data or worry about missing data they just:

- read the data
- throw it at the queue
- forget the data
- sleep or move on to the next reading to take as needed

Remember: getting data from the devices on to the queue is time critical so no "thinking" in this part of this operation.

I would consider batching your data - i.e. you add single items which get added to a block of let's say 32 readings. That whole block gets added to the queue. When the data is read it doesn't take a single reading but a batch of x items (in this case 32). This means the queue handles many more writes than reads.

Your second stage is where all the brains are. This buffer (or buffers depending on how many files you're writing to) reads from the queue and orders it. You have to decide on the rules of how it gets ordered. But this operation is not time critical. It reads from the queue, looks at what device the data is for, what the timestamp is and works out whether or not there are any missing readings due to timeouts and constructs the data that gets saved to disk. If you're creating 1 file per device then this is where the data gets separated out.

The point of separating the two operations is that the time critical part of your work is not held up by the relatively slow part of sorting it and writing it to disk. Don't just keep adding threads to your model - do the reverse and get by on the minimum you can. The 2nd stage should loop much, much more slowly than the first.

This is a rough idea of how it would work:

[image: Rough drawing of the 2 stages]

As Doc said in Back to The Future, "You'll have to forgive the crudity of the model."
I know this is only general guidaince but I hope it helps you and gives a shove in the right direction.

Good luck and Kind Regards!

Adam.

Comment: As Doc said "great Jupiter"!!! I've write some code but i've some doubt / problem ..The service start 2 task             this.tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
            this.task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => readData(token), token);

            this.tokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token1 = tokenSource1.Token;
            this.task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => readQueue(token1), token1);

Comment: When stop service, will stop also a tasks. The first (read data) is ok but the second (read from queue) must stopping only when the queue will be empty. This code may be ok?
this.tokenSource.Cancel(); while (this.dataQueue.Count != 0) {
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);} this.tokenSource1.Cancel(); try
{this.task.Wait(); this.task1.Wait(); } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
finally {this.tokenSource.Dispose(); this.tokenSource1.Dispose(); this.dataQueue.Clear(); }

Comment: There will always be half-formed data in your buffers for stage 2. The second stage will just have to make sure that 1) it only writes fully-formed data to disk 2) the disk files are closed when the process terminates. Have your second stage worker check an event for termination and signal an event when it's ready. Your main thread signals it to terminate and it responds when it's happy and then does no more work. Your main thread can then kill the whole process.